# how do I configure socketio on aws ec2

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, flask-socketio

Here is what postman returns when I try making socket connections

I'm trying to do real time messaging using flask-socketio. when I try to make socket connections I get the error bellow.

```
Error:{error}
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://ec2-18-234-207-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: +6WOYDKiGdr5DMv3EihFHQ==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2ODc1NDAxODIsImlhdCI6MTY4NDk0ODE4Miwic3ViIjozNjk1LCJzdHJpbmciOiI1NzAySkw2SFkifQ.L7CBLJClIBFT9ZF6gJ2rQAl5gmMU4FG8sWpWm1woxzk
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: ec2-18-234-207-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Here is a sample function that I'm using on a file send_message.py:

```
def emit_message(locator, message):
    sent_message = {
        "message_id": message["message_id"],
        "text": message["message"],
        "createdAt": message["timestamp"],
        "sender": message["sender"],
        "receiver": message["receiver"],
        "user": {
            "locator": message["sender"],
            "name": message["display_name"],
            "avatar": message["profile_image"],
        },
        "image": 0,
        # You can also add a video prop:
        "video": 0,
        # Mark the message as sent, using one tick
        "sent": 1,
        # Mark the message as received, using two tick
        "received": 1,
        # Mark the message as pending with a clock loader
        "pending": 0,
        # Any additional custom parameters are passed through
        "total": 0,
        "statusCode": 200
    }

    socketio = app.config['socket']
    room = get_user_room.get(locator)
    socketio.emit('receiveMessage', sent_message, room=room)
```

here is where I call the function on a file named server.py:

```
import flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room
from messages import send_message

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", logger = True, engineio_logger= True)  # ,async_mode="gevent_uwsgi"
app.config["socket"] = socketio


@socketio.on("tena")
def socket_op(message):
    header = request.headers.get("Authorization")
    _id = request.sid

    subject = 0
    msg_received = 0
    try:
        msg_received = message
        subject = msg_received["subject"]
    except Exception:
        pass

    if subject == "sendMessage":
        return send_message.send(header, msg_received)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
```